# Evitar a duplicidade de data e hora para o mesmo profissional em agendamento

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Amigos estou tentando criar uma agenda para uma clinica odontológica, mas estou tendo dificuldade para evitar de que o cliente agende uma data e hora que já tenha sido agendada para aquele profissional selecionado.
Por exemplo, alguém já agendou o atendimento com o profissional João a data 01/06/2015 as 12:00Hs, eu gostaria de que outra pessoa não tenha condições de agendar para o mesmo profissional a mesma data e hora, que o sistema avisasse para escolher outra data e hora para esse profissional ou agendar para outro profissional disponível para a data e hora desejada.

Eu estou usando esse código abaixo que cadastra, mas não impede a duplicidade de cadastro do agendamento.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$cel = $_POST['cel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$plano = $_POST['plano'];
$horas = $_POST['horas'];
$prof = $_POST['prof'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$tempo = date("dd/mm/YY His",time());


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE = '{$data}' AND horas ='{$horas}' AND prof = '{$prof}'");
if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= agenda.php'>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      alert(\"Esta data e hora já esta agendada para esse Profissional!<br />
              Tente com outro Profissional ou outra data e hora!<br />
              Obrigado!!!\");</script>";

 return die;

 }else{

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare ('INSERT INTO agendar (nome, tel, cel, email, plano, prof, data, horas)
                        VALUES (:nome, :tel, :cel, :email, :plano, :prof, :data, :horas)');

 $stmt->execute(array(':nome' => $nome,
                     ':tel' => $tel,
                     ':cel' => $cel,
                     ':email' => $email,
                     ':plano' => $plano,
                     ':prof' => $prof,
                     ':horas' => $horas,
                     ':data' => $data,
                     ':data' => $data,
                     ));

  if($stmt == ''){
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Ocorreu um erro ao Agendar sua Avaliação!');
          </script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Avaliação Agendada com sucesso!');
          </script>";

}}}
?>
```

Uso essa linha de código `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE '".$data."' AND horas ='".$horas."' AND prof = '".$prof."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1){` no Mysql para evitar a duplicidade, e funciona legal, impedindo o agendamento.

Adaptei para o PDO ficando assim `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM agendar WHERE data LIKE = '{$data}' AND horas ='{$horas}' AND prof = '{$prof}'");
    if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){` mas não sei se fiz a adaptação corretamente, e acho que pode ser ai que eu esteja errando!!!

Conforme solicitado estou inserindo o código do FORM abaixo:

```
<form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>
<tr>
<td align="center"><span style="font:15px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000066;">AGENDE HOJE MESMO SUA AVALIAÇÃO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>Nome:</span><input style="width:250px" type="text" name="nome" value=''></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>Telefone Residêncial:</span><input style="width:166px" type="text" name="tel" value='(21) '></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>Telefone Celular:</span><input style="width:188px" type="text" name="cel" value='(21) '></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>E-mail:</span><input style="width:247px" type="text" name="email" value=''></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<?php 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT plano FROM planos');
$stmt-> execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$plano = $_POST['plano'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE agendar SET plano = :plano');
$stmt->execute(array( ':plano' => $plano));
}
?>
<select name="plano">
<?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['plano'];?>"><?php echo $row['plano'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select><br />
<?php 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT prof FROM profissionais');
$stmt-> execute(); 
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$prof = $_POST['prof'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE agendar SET prof = :prof');
$stmt->execute(array( ':prof' => $prof));
}
?>
<select name="prof">
 <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['prof'];?>"><?php echo $row['prof'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select><br />
</td>
</tr>                       
<tr>
 <td><input width="10" type="text" name="data" value="Data" id="data" />
<img src="img/calendar.png" width="30" height="30" style="float: none; margin-top: -22px; cursor: pointer;" title="Selecione a data do Agendamento!" onClick="$('#data').focus();" />
<?php 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT horas FROM horarios');
$stmt-> execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$horas = $_POST['horas'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE agendar SET horas = :horas');
$stmt->execute(array( ':horas' => $horas));
}
?>
<select name="horas">
<?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['horas'];?>"><?php echo $row['horas'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select><br />
</td>
</tr>                       
<td><input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value="Agendar" />  <span>Se preferir, ligue para: (21)2290.3702</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Se os amigos puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Abraços à todos!!!

Comment: Acho mais facil você  liberar apenas os horarios disponiveis para a pessoa postar.. da mesma forma como funciona um check-in de voo... o usuario so pode escolher as cadeiras disponíveis.  seria isso?

Comment: vc poderia colocar o formulario que o usuario cadastra o horario tambem?

Comment: OK  Andrei, acabei de inserir o código do **FORM** que estou usando.
Acho que foi isso que vc. pediu, estou correto?
Agradeço a atenção, valeu!!!

Answer (score 0):

Analisei seus códigos, e acho que você poderia fazer em etapas para não ter problema com duplicidade...

Antes do usuário cadastrar nome, endereço, etc... ele tem que escolher 1 dia que é melhor para ele fazer a consulta na clínica. Depois ele escolhe os horários que estão disponíveis naquela data selecionada. E depois ele cadastra os dados pessoais...

Formatei seu código assim

**agendar.php**

```
      // aqui o codigo verifica se existe na url a data e a hora, se não existir ele executa baixo...
     <?php if(!isset($_GET['data']) && !isset($_GET['hora'])){ ?>

    <form method="get" action="agendar.php">
     <td><input width="10" type="text" name="data" value="Data" id="data" />
    <img src="img/calendar.png" width="30" height="30" style="float: none; margin-top: -22px; cursor: pointer;" title="Selecione a data do Agendamento!" onClick="$('#data').focus();" />
    <input width="10" type="submit" name="envia" value="Selecionar" /> 
     </form>
    // aqui o codigo verifica se existe na url a data e a hora, se não existir a hora ele executa baixo...
   <?php  } elseif(isset($_GET['data']) && !isset($_GET['hora']) { ?>

     <form method="get" action="agendar.php">

    <?php 

    //***** alterado ***** > a variável que estava escrita era a $pdo
    $conn= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");

    $data = $_GET['data'];
    //MUITO IMPORTATE: aqui estou selecionando apenas os horários vazios da tabela horário conforma a tabela agendar daquela data selecionada.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT horas FROM horarios LEFT JOIN agendar ON agendar.horas = horarios.horas WHERE horarios.horas IS NULL AND agendar.data = $data");
    $stmt-> execute();
    //repare que eu alterei esta linha de código pois não estava funcionando com ASSOC, afinal oque você precisa é de um array
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

    $horas = $_POST['horas'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE agendar SET horas = :horas');
    $stmt->execute(array( ':horas' => $horas));
    }
    ?>
    <select name="horas">
    <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['horas'];?>"><?php echo $row['horas'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select><br />
     <input width="10" type="submit" name="envia" value="Selecionar" />
   </form>
         // aqui o codigo verifica se existe na url a data e a hora, se existir a hora e a data ele executa baixo..
        <?php  } elseif(isset($_GET['data']) && isset($_GET['hora']) { ?>

       <form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:15px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000066;">AGENDE HOJE MESMO SUA AVALIAÇÃO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="center"><span style="font:15px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000066;">Data selecionada: <input name="data" value="<?php echo $_GET['data'] ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:15px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000066;">Hora selecionada:  <input name="hora" value="<?php echo $_GET['hora'] ?>"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><span>Nome:</span><input style="width:250px" type="text" name="nome" value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><span>Telefone Residêncial:</span><input style="width:166px" type="text" name="tel" value='(21) '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><span>Telefone Celular:</span><input style="width:188px" type="text" name="cel" value='(21) '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><span>E-mail:</span><input style="width:247px" type="text" name="email" value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        <?php  }  ?>
```

agora é só inserir no banco de dados

Fiz com o method get só para você ter uma idéia.

Mas aquela seleção da hora do dia que estão disponíveis vai evitar duplicidade para voce, pois ele só vai selecionar os campos hora da tabela horario que estão disponíveis.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Valeu Andrei, vou dar uma analisada no seu código, pois assim aprendo um pouco mais...rsrsrsrs...
Mais uma vez BRIGADÃO pela sua atenção.
Abraços!!!

Comment: Tranquilo Murilo, abraço

Comment: Andrei, inseri as suas alterações, porém ele esta se referindo ao seguinte erro quando seleciono uma data e clico em selecionar: **Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\wamp\www\site\agenda\agendar.php on line 46**, e a linha 46 esta assim: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT horas FROM horarios LEFT JOIN agendar ON agendar.horas = horarios.horas WHERE horarios.horas IS NULL AND agendar.data = $data");`. Se puderes me ajudar com esse erro, ficarei grato. Abraços amigo!!!

Comment: achei o erro... digitei um comentário lá com ***** para você visualizar.. Mas veja, este código é apenas um modelo de como você deve agir...

Comment: Talvez ele não funcione da forma correta pois não estou fazendo testes e tal...